# Should I use both Cypress and Jest together?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, cypress

I'm learning both Jest and Cypress at same time. I know that they are not direct competitors because Cypress is focused on E2E and Jest on unit testing. For now I have implemented in my project both Jest and Cypress with few tests.

But actually most things I can test in both Cypress and Jest, and often I have hard time to decide with what write my test. Also it is harder to maintain compared to single test library.

I'm wondering - how often is Cypress (or alternative) and Jest (or alternative) used together? Is it really standard and good practice to use both? Or most developers/teams sticks with single one solution and it is fine?

**Update edit**: It was a long time since this question was asked. I got compromise that was also suggested in comment. Instead using only Cypress or Cypress + Jest, I'm using Cypress + new Cypress Component Testing (so no Jest). Thanks to that I'm having same library and assertions (easier to manage) but can test both e2e and components.

Comment: They are orthogonal. Cypress uses a browser. Jest uses fake DOM and isn't eligible for frontend e2e or intergration tests that need full DOM support, unless used with Puppeteer or else. Once you have a good idea what kind of test you're writing, the choice is quite straightforward. If you have difficulties in choosing between unit, e2e, integration, etc tests then that's the issue that needs to be solved first.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

short answers: It's very common to use Jest and Cypress in the same codebase.

**Unit, Integration, or E2E tests**

With component Libraries like Vue and React, the line between integration and unit tests can get a bit fuzzy. We can even use the same tools(Jest & Cypress)for both cases, which makes things even more confusing. I recommend that you aim to test "user stories" or, in other words, make sure that users can always perform key actions. For example:

1. Can the user fill and submit a form?
2. Can the user add products to the cart?
3. Does the hamburger menu responds to clicks?

Some of these tests will involve one component, others will involve two and some will require the entire application. I prefer writing smaller tests(unit and integration) using Jest and [testing library](https://testing-library.com/) because of the quick feedback loop. I get to develop and run my tests at, almost, the same time.

Eventually, you'll run into cases that involve so many moving parts(components) that using Jest is not an option. This is where Cypress shines, it's great for testing your end-to-end workflows.

Comment: With the new component testing library I can see Cypress replacing Jest for unit testing your components as well. Based on a video I've seen where Lachlan Miller was playing with it, it seemed snappy enough.

Comment: Does Cypress support mocking React Hooks? (useContext, etc.)

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, but wanted to provide additional clarity for why you would use both Cypress and Jest. I have used both on multiple projects. They each address separate testing concerns:

#### Jest

For running unit tests. Unit tests uphold **business logic** or just that ensure your methods return the expected value for lots of different cases. Generally these tests are for methods in services, but not limited to them.

#### Cypress

For running end-to-end, or functional tests. Cypress is for **testing the UI specifically** by interacting with it and making assertions on it. Calls to the backend are generally stubbed, meaning you control the response in the test, because Cypress is not for testing the backend.

Together, Cypress and Jest provide a complete testing solution for the frontend.

Answer (score 4):

I use cypress for e2e tests and component testing. I test the behaiviors of those types with cypress. With jest i do unit testing. With jest i test logic/business-logic in the frontend.